# Scala Lazy Collection can some one please explainfor the following behaviour

Tags: scala

I have a normal list and defined two filters on it. I am filtering the list with first filter, then filtering the output with the next filter and taking the last element.

1. I am doing the above operation on the List object lst (NORMAL LIST)
2. I am doing the above operation on the lst.view (LAZY LIST)

The second operation seems to take more iterations. It seems to restart the operation all over again at one point. Pls find the code below. Can some one please explain the reason for that?

```
object SolutionTest {
  val lst = List(("Mark", 32), ("Bob", 22), ("Jane", 8), ("Jill", 21),("Nick", 50), ("Nancy", 42), ("Mike", 19), ("Sara", 12), ("Paula", 42),("John", 21))
                                              //> lst  : List[(String, Int)] = List((Mark,32), (Bob,22), (Jane,8), (Jill,21), 
                                              //| (Nick,50), (Nancy,42), (Mike,19), (Sara,12), (Paula,42), (John,21))
    lst.size                                  //> res0: Int = 10

  def filter1(tup:(String, Int)):Boolean={
    println("from filter1 "+ tup)
    val (_, age) = tup
    age > 17
  }                                               //> filter1: (tup: (String, Int))Boolean

  def filter2(tup:(String, Int)):Boolean={
    println("from filter2 "+ tup)
    val (name, _) = tup
    name.startsWith("J")
  }                                               //> filter2: (tup: (String, Int))Boolean


//NORMAL LIST                                                  
lst.filter(filter1).filter(filter2).last  //> from filter1 (Mark,32)
                                              //| from filter1 (Bob,22)
                                              //| from filter1 (Jane,8)
                                              //| from filter1 (Jill,21)
                                              //| from filter1 (Nick,50)
                                              //| from filter1 (Nancy,42)
                                              //| from filter1 (Mike,19)
                                              //| from filter1 (Sara,12)
                                              //| from filter1 (Paula,42)
                                              //| from filter1 (John,21)
                                              //| from filter2 (Mark,32)
                                              //| from filter2 (Bob,22)
                                              //| from filter2 (Jill,21)
                                              //| from filter2 (Nick,50)
                                              //| from filter2 (Nancy,42)
                                              //| from filter2 (Mike,19)
                                              //| from filter2 (Paula,42)
                                              //| from filter2 (John,21)
                                              //| res1: (String, Int) = (John,21)

//LAZY LIST
lst.view.filter(filter1).filter(filter2).last
                                              //> from filter1 (Mark,32)
                                              //| from filter2 (Mark,32)
                                              //| from filter1 (Bob,22)
                                              //| from filter2 (Bob,22)
                                              //| from filter1 (Jane,8)
                                              //| from filter1 (Jill,21)
                                              //| from filter2 (Jill,21)
                                              //| from filter1 (Mark,32) RESTARTING THE OPERATION HERE!!!
                                              //| from filter2 (Mark,32)
                                              //| from filter1 (Bob,22)
                                              //| from filter2 (Bob,22)
                                              //| from filter1 (Jane,8)
                                              //| from filter1 (Jill,21)
                                              //| from filter2 (Jill,21)
                                              //| from filter1 (Nick,50)
                                              //| from filter2 (Nick,50)
                                              //| from filter1 (Nancy,42)
                                              //| from filter2 (Nancy,42)
                                              //| from filter1 (Mike,19)
                                              //| from filter2 (Mike,19)
                                              //| from filter1 (Sara,12)
                                              //| from filter1 (Paula,42)
                                              //| from filter2 (Paula,42)
                                              //| from filter1 (John,21)
                                              //| from filter2 (John,21)
                                              //| res2: (String, Int) = (John,21)
}
```

Comment: @kolmar answers it well. To avoid the extra processing when using "last" in a view, place "force" after the filters: `lst.view.filter(filter1).filter(filter2).force.last`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first operations before your comment "RESTARTING HERE" come from looking for the first element in the filtered sequence. Scala starts filtering until it finds the first element in the result `(Jill,21)`.  After this it actually begins processing the whole sequence.

This happens because `last` is [implemented](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L453) in class `TraversableLike` like this:

```
def last: A = {
  var lst = head
  for (x <- this)
    lst = x
  lst
}
```

It calls `head` before really going through the sequence. Simple `view`s don't use caching, so after filtering a bit to find `head`, it has to restart.

Other functions on views may fail to exhibit this restarting behaviour. For example `lst.view.filter(filter1).filter(filter2).lastOption` only runs through the sequence once.